# How to populate Listbox / dropdown box /select box from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu

I need write a custom array or JSON to populate a Listbox/dropdown box/select box and add an attribute `selected="selected"`.

For example:

```
<select id="test1" name="selectB" class="Field">
<option value="NO" selected="selected">No (Recommended)</option>
<option value="YES">Yes</option>
</select>
```

I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where is your data coming from? You want php to take the results of a database query, and create a select with that?

Comment: This very similar question was just posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249825/auto-populate-a-select-box-using-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array("value"=>"NO","label"=>"No (Recommended)","selected"=>true),
    array("value"=>"YES","label"=>"Yes","selected"=>false),
);


?>

<select>
    <?php foreach($array as $option) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>" <?php if($option['selected']){ ?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>
             <?php echo $option['label'] ?>
        </option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

json equivalent of the array is:

```
[{"value":"1","label":"No (Recommended)","selected":true},{"value":"2","label":"Yes","selected":false}]
```

which is the output of `json_enconde($array);`

Comment: +1 I like how you adapted your answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249825/auto-populate-a-select-box-using-an-array-in-php. :)

Comment: Can you ,please, tell me how to use JSON mode - function to output the results ?