# Putting an array into a drop down box?

Tags: php, html

I'm making a forum software, and I need to put an array into a drop down selection box. Like in the administration panel, have a drop down box that lists all of the current forums, so you choose one to delete or modify.

I can get the array fine, but how would I put that in a drop down box, or is there an alternative?

```
$select_forums = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM forums");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_forums, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf (" Name: %s", $row["name"]);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249825/auto-populate-a-select-box-using-an-array-in-php Here you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select>
  <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_forums, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>"><?php echo $row["name"] ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, that works, but, it's skipping the first forum and not putting it in the list, any idea why?

Comment: Are you using any other mysql functions between the query and this code? The `fetch` functions use an iterator; you may need to use `mysql_data_seek` to reset it.

Comment: Follow nkorth.....comment other mysql functions between query and code...you will get the bug.......

Comment: make it shorter: instead of <?php echo do <?=